# Git Fetch Fails

Tags: git, jenkins, exception

I am brand new to jenkins. i just set up jenkins on a windows 2016 server. i am creating a new job that will use git for scm. when i go to build the job it creates the folders and inits git. it gets stuck on the git fetch. it times out. i have jenkins set up as a service. i have it use a local administrator account to log in to the server to try to eliminate permissions problems. the error shown in the log from the git fetch is GitException then returned status code -1073741510. i searched and can't find that error number anywhere. if i open a command window and go to the exact same folder being logged in with the exact same user and issue the exact same fetch command it works fine. can anyone help me figure out where to go from here to figure this out?

Here is the build log.

i abstracted the names of things:

```
13:01:51 Started by user Admin
13:01:51 Building in workspace D:\Jenkins\workspace\MyProject - Staging
13:01:51 Cloning the remote Git repository
13:01:51 Cloning repository ssh://myserver.com/git/Software.git
13:01:51 > git.exe init D:\Jenkins\workspace\MyProject - Staging # timeout=10
13:01:51 Fetching upstream changes from ssh://myserver.com/git/Software.git
13:01:51 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
13:01:52 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
13:01:52 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress ssh://myserver.com/git/Software.git +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/ # timeout=5
13:06:52 ERROR: Timeout after 5 minutes
13:06:52 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
13:06:52 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --progress ssh://myserver.com/git/Software.git +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/" returned status code -1073741510:
13:06:52 stdout:
13:06:52 stderr:
13:06:52 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
13:06:52 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
13:06:52 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
13:06:52 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
13:06:52 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:655)
13:06:52 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
13:06:52 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
13:06:52 at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
13:06:52 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
13:06:52 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
13:06:52 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
13:06:52 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
13:06:52 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
13:06:52 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
13:06:52 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
13:06:52 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
13:06:52 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
13:06:52 Finished: FAILURE
```

When I manually do the git fetch at a command line in the same folder it works fine and takes less than 2 minutes.

Comment: Make sure you've definied the "Path to Git executable" in the Global Tool Configuration section.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I will make sure of that.

Comment: Jenkins hosted in windows is not advisable. git clone, git fetch are the most common commands and don't fail in Jenkins.  If you can, share us your script in jenkins, Are you trying in a clean folder without jenkins?

Comment: not sure what script you are referring to (noob here). it is all created in the GUI. i just created a project and added the git component and filled in the blanks.deploying it on windows is not an option in this case. if jenkins doesn't work on windows, then i will find something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem very similar to yours.

In short one of quickly solution is Uninstall/Re-install git-for-window and ensure to disable the option “Enable Git Credential Manager” during the installation.

This option is enabled by default and set the git property credential.helper at a system level. This forces the git client to use the Git Credentials Manager for Windows instead of the local configuration provided by Jenkins. Consequently it makes your build either hang (if running the node as an System Account) or fail (if running the node as a local User).

[Git for windows installer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtA3K.png)

Other two solutions available on this link.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221046888-Build-Hang-or-Fail-with-Git-for-Windows

Comment: I was using an older git 1.9.5 and it doesn't have that option, so I uninstalled that and installed 2.20. I made sure to not check the credentials manager install. Now I get an error that git-upload-pack isn't a valid command. before I had to add the path to the cmd to the environment path. that folder doesn't have git-upload-pack. where is that for 2.20?

Comment: I had to reinstall and this time enable the git bash commands from windows commands. now it works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At times you get this error when you change your system password and then try to fetch or pull.

Go to Credential Manager.

Under Windows credential you may find the bit bucket.

I would recommend to edit it and add your new system password.

This should solve the issue.